# How to cut seconds from an interval column?

Tags: postgresql

In my table results from column `work_time` (`interval` type) display as `200:00:00`. Is it possible to cut the seconds part, so it will be displayed as `200:00`? Or, even better: `200h00min` (I've seen it accepts `h` unit in insert so why not load it like this?).
Preferably, by altering `work_time` column, not by changing the `select` query.

Comment: If you want to _display_ something, [`TO_CHAR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) is your friend. See ["Interval Output"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) for a way to affect the default output format for the interval type.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should do by altering a column but by changing the select query in some way.  If you change the column you are changing storage and functional uses, and that's not good.  To change it on output, you need to modify how it is retrieved.

You have two basic options.  The first is to modify your select queries directly, using `to_char(myintervalcol, 'HH24:MI')`

However if your issue is that you have a common format you want to have universal access to in your select query, PostgreSQL has a neat trick I call "table methods."  You can attach a function to a table in such a way that you can call it in a similar (but not quite identical) syntax to a new column.  In this case you would do something like:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myinterval_nosecs(mytable) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL 
 IMMUTABLE AS
 $$
     SELECT to_char($1.myintervalcol, 'HH24:MI');
 $$;
```

This works on the row input, not on the underlying table.  As it always returns the same information for the same input, you can mark it immutable and even index the output (meaning it can be run at plan time and indexed used).

To call this, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT myinterval_nosecs(m) FROM mytable m;
```

But you can then use the special syntax above to rewrite that as:

```
SELECT m.myinterval_nosecs FROM mytable m;
```

Note that since myinterval_nosecs is a function you cannot omit the `m.` at the beginning.  This is because the query planner will rewrite the query in the former syntax and will not guess as to which relation you mean to run it against.